# React: enable signup button after filling out a form in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wanna activate the button after I check all the inputs from the user by the function ValidateForm(). If all of fields are correct due to validateForm(), then I can see the green button activate. The problem: how can I check **ALL** of the fields after finishing filling out, and not only when I fill out the first field.

```
 const validateForm = (values) => {
   const errors = {}; 
   errors.firstname = values.firstname.length >= 3;
   errors.lastname = values.lastname.length >= 3;
   errors.email = values.email.length >= 3;       
   
   return errors; 
}
const SignUp = () => {

   const eintraege = { firstname: '', lastname: '', email: '' };
   const [formValues  , setFormValues] = useState(eintraege);
   const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
   const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(true);
 
   const formChangeHandler = (event) => {
          const { name, value } = event.target;
          const nextValues = {...formValues, [name]: value };       
          setErrors(validateForm(nextValues));
   }; 
   
   const handleSubmit = (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          setButtonDisabled(true);
   };
         
   const btnChanged = () => {
          return (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) ? 
                            setButtonDisabled(true) : 
                              setButtonDisabled(false) ;              
   };
    
  return ( 
    <FormBox onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
        <ProfileImage />
            <InputWrapper gridPosition="firstname-input">
            <Input 
                   type="text"
                   name='firstname'
                   value={formValues.firstname}
                   placeholder='Vorname'
                   hasError={errors.firstname === false}
                   onChangeHandler={formChangeHandler}
            />
            <Error errors={errors} name="firstname" />
            </InputWrapper>

            <Button className="btn" disabled={buttonDisabled}/>
    </FormBox> 
  );
 }
```

Comment: You have to run validateForm each time form values change. Add useEffect with formValues as dependency and execute form validation logic there

Comment: This code fragment is not enough to reproduce your problem